# Pandas read_hdf is giving "can only use an iterator or chunksize on a table" error

Tags: python, pandas, hdf

I have an h5 data file, which includes key `rawreport`

I can read the `rawreport` and save as dataframe using `read_hdf(filename, "rawreport")` without any problems. But the data has 17 mil rows and i'd like to use chunking

When I ran this code

```
chunksize = 10**6
someval = 100
df = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_hdf(filename, 'rawreport',  chunksize=chunksize, where='datetime < someval'):
    df = pd.concat([df, chunk], ignore_index=True)
```

I get "TypeError: can only use an iterator or chunksize on a table"

What does it mean that the `rawreport` isn't a table and how could I overcome this issue? I'm not the person who created the h5 file.

Answer (score 0):

Chunking is only possible if your file was written in a Table format using `PyTables`. This must be specified when your file was first written:

```
df.to_hdf('rawreport', format = 'table')
```

If this wasn't specified when you wrote the file, then Pandas defaults to using a `fixed` format. This means that while the file can be quickly written and read later, it does mean that the entire dataframe must be read into memory. Unfortunately, this means that chunking and other options in `read_hdf` to specify particular rows or columns can't be used here.